# Call react native javascript code when android app is not running

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have a widget which starts a intent which invokes react-native javascript code. It does not work when the app is not running as i get 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent app is in background uid UidRecord

I understand that android stoped users being able to do this and recommend the JobScheduler. But i still need a way of calling code across the react-native bridge and not on a timer.

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundTask.class);

    context.startService(serviceIntent);
    HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
}


public class BackgroundTask extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
    @Override
    protected @Nullable
        HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
                "WidgetTask",
                extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null,
                5000,
                false);
    }
}
```

I get the following error

> 2019-09-08 20:13:18.874 796-796/com.mypackage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: mypackage, PID: 796
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver mypackage.MyAppWidget: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to
>   start service Intent { cmp=mypackage/.BackgroundTask }: app is in
>   background uid UidRecord{9b991cb u0a160 RCVR idle change:uncached
>   procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}